# How to get around proxy server

Tags: proxy, remote-access

I normally use Logmein to access my home computer from wherever. However, recently my company just installed a proxy server that automatically kills my LogMeIn program when I try to connect to my home computer.

Is there any program out there that will allow me to connect to my home computer even bypassing the proxy server?

Comment: I think you might get into trouble for trying to bypass the company IT policy. They've obviously introduced it for a reason. Have you thought of asking?

Comment: Unless they have started blocking your specific IP address (which could be gotten around with a proxy) then they are likely looking for VPN traffic directly. The only way then to work around that would be encryption, but as other have mentioned your best bet is probably to ask the IT department.

Comment: yes, i agree asking them is a must. on the other hand, i also was wondering if there's any program that can connect directly to my computer via..say port 80.

Answer (score 3):

Talk to the person/department responsible for the proxy server.  They can easily permit your traffic but perhaps there is a reason they don't allow in the first place?

Comment: right, because they care a lot about security. but i will talk to them.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to check [LogMeIn's website](http://community.logmeinrescue.com/logmein/board/message?message.uid=12329#U12329)...Where you'll find that they're no help what-so-ever.

The only way to do it is to either bypass the proxy, or to fool it into thinking your traffic is legitimate. The latter is probably right out; you need to connect to LMI, and they're not allowing that. The former one is extremely unlikely unless they've whitelisted some site that will proxy your traffic for you.

Speaking as an admin, I run IP/Traffic reports all the time to watch for viruses and crackers, and just so I know who watches streaming media, so I can mess with them (grey area by our corporate policy, but I can throttle them, or kick them off at certain times of the day, etc, and they can't complain). I would notice a statistical deviation if you (hypothetically) suddenly started tunneling a VPN connection out on port 80, or something.

Setting up the system is challenging, but even a monkey would notice stuff like that once it's up. If you can't convince them to make an exception, I'd give up.

Answer (score 1):

try to set up tunnel like OpenVPN at your place using 443 port or use alternative service

Comment: unfortunately I don't see comment functionality, and I don't see any reason that it should be down-voted.

Comment: @Ramhound Users with less than 50 reputation can't post comments.